# Need to understand a specific signalr client side code

Tags: signalr

few line is not clear to me. so please someone explain how those line will work.

```
<div id="currentHitCount"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var hub = connection.createProxy("hitCounter");
hub.on("showHitCount", function (hitCount) {
if (hitCount > 1) {
$('#currentHitCount')
.html("This site has had " + hitCount + " hits.");
}
else {
$('#currentHitCount')
.html("This site has had " + hitCount + " hit.");
}
});
connection.start().done(function () {
hub.invoke("addHit");
});
});
</script>
```

1) why `createproxy()` is used? when it is required?

2) what is the meaning of `hub.invoke("addHit"); ?`

what will happen when we call hub.invoke ?

3) when this function will be called `hub.on("showHitCount", function (hitCount) ?`

please explain the code in details. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It creates a hub proxy, you can also do

```
$.connection.hitCounter.client.showHitCount = function(hitCount) {
};
```

2) `addHit` is a server side method on the `hitCounter` Hub

3) My guess is that code in the `addHit` method will trigger the client side method `showHitCount`

Comment: i just like to know we could establish hub connection from client side without this line code var hub = connection.createProxy("hitCounter"); so just tell me when people use createProxy() function to connect to server side hub?

Comment: i do not know how to send msg to specific user in group. please share this knowledge. thanks